# Prevent TestNg sharing data between parallel tests

Tags: testng

**Goal**: To run 2 classes in independently in parallel where each test stores the Method name into a variable that could be accessed later in the test.

**Issue**: When the tests are run in parallel, they start sharing data between themselves thus corrupting the tests.

If you see the console output this is wrong:

```
INFO: Name of Test from Before Method: classB_Method1
INFO: Name of Test from Before Method: classB_Method1
```

Since these are two separate classes and methods are being run. And 
I set the correct name here:

```
  !! Setting Method name to: classA_Method1
    !! Setting Method name to: classB_Method1
```

The output should look like this:

```
INFO: Name of Test from Before Method: classA_Method1
INFO: Name of Test from Before Method: classB_Method1
```

**TestA**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import com.xxxx.util.*;

public class TestA {


    @Test(/*dataProvider = "DP_MVPLoan_Login",*/ groups = {"parallel_test" }, invocationCount = 1, priority = 2, enabled = true)
    public void classA_Method1(/*String... excelData*/) throws Exception {

    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // ****SetUp and Tear Down

    @BeforeTest(alwaysRun=true)
    public void setupClass() throws Exception {
    }


    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun=true)
    public void setupMethod(Method method) throws Exception {
        SeleniumHelperDebug.setCurrentMethodName(method.getName());
        SeleniumHelperDebug.defaultBeforeMethod(); 

    }
```

}

**TestB**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import com.xxxx.util.*;

public class TestB {


@Test(/*dataProvider = "DP_MVPLoan_Login",*/ groups = { "parallel_test" }, invocationCount = 1, priority = 2, enabled = true)
public void classB_Method1(/*String... excelData*/) throws Exception {

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// ****SetUp and Tear Down

@BeforeTest(alwaysRun=true)
public void setupClass() throws Exception {
}


@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun=true)
public void setupMethod(Method method) throws Exception {
    SeleniumHelperDebug.setCurrentMethodName(method.getName());
    SeleniumHelperDebug.defaultBeforeMethod(); 

}
```

}

**Helper Method**

```
public class SeleniumHelperDebug { 



    //Name of the method/Test being run
    private static String currentMethodName;
    public static String getCurrentMethodName() {
        return currentMethodName;
    }
    public static void setCurrentMethodName(String currentMethodName) {
        System.out.println("!! Setting Method name to: "+ currentMethodName);
        SeleniumHelperDebug.currentMethodName = currentMethodName;
    }

    //Setup Method. BeforeTest
    public static void defaultBeforeMethod() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(500);
        /*setCurrentMethodName(method.getName());*/
        System.out.println("INFO: Name of Test from Before Method: " +getCurrentMethodName() );


        System.out.println("REMINDER: Keep Browser Window in Foreground to Help prevent F@ilures");
    }
}
```

**Testng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="classes" verbose="2" thread-count="2">

<!-- 
<listeners>
<listener class-name="com.progressfin.util.WebDriverListener"></listener>
</listeners -->>
<tests>
    <test name="Test" preserve-order="true">
        <!-- <parameter name="browserName" value="firefox"></parameter> -->

    <groups>
      <run>
        <include name="parallel_test"/>
      </run>
    </groups>


    <classes>

        <class name="com.xxxx.test.TestA" />
        <class name="com.xxxx.test.TestB"/>
    </classes>


    </test> <!-- Test -->
</tests>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**Console Output**

```
...
... TestNG 6.8.6 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...

[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\samuel.safyan\workspace\JavaSelenium2\testNgParallelism2.xml

[TestRunner] Starting executor for test Test with time out:2147483647 milliseconds.
!! Setting Method name to: classA_Method1
!! Setting Method name to: classB_Method1
INFO: Name of Test from Before Method: classB_Method1
REMINDER: Keep Browser Window in Foreground to Help prevent F@ilures
INFO: Name of Test from Before Method: classB_Method1
REMINDER: Keep Browser Window in Foreground to Help prevent F@ilures
PASSED: classB_Method1
PASSED: classA_Method1

===============================================
    Test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SeleniumHelperDebug class is static, hence not thread safe. Is there any reason why you cannot have an instance per test?

What problem are you trying to solve with the SeleniumHelperDebug class?

There may be a better solution which is threadsafe but it is not clear what that class is trying to achieve

Comment: Good feedback Robbie. I didn't have a specific reason for setting them as static. I'm reasonably new to Java and was following examples on the interwebs. The SeleniumHelperDebug class helps with tests, by say, creating a screenshot of a failed test using the syntax Classname_MethodName_Timestamp.png  so does using instances instead of static guarantee thread safety? because it seems to have solved my issue

Comment: A static class could be used but you would need to pass the driver as argument to the methods

Answer (score 2):

My advice:

```
1.  Dont use static webdriver instances.
2.  Dont use ThreadLocal
```

So what is the answer?

```
Well, you don't need to handle the threads if your using a testrunner that can
fork threads for you.  I use TestNG, and in that case I just pass DriverHelper
objects as arguments into my test methods from  my Factory or my DataProvider 
method.   The DataProvider creates multiple helper instances and then once the
DriverHelper is inside my @Test annotated method, I instantiate the WebDriver 
browser and proceed with test.   If my DataProvider returns 10 items, then 
TestNG iterates it 10 times, each on a different thread.  Of course, this is
overly simplified, because you need to pay attention to the test lifecycle, and
take care to not open the browser until after you are in the Test method, but
it should get you started.
```

To help get you started.  Here is a non-working example, as a hint:

```
@DataProvider(name = "testdata")
public static Object[][] getTestData( ITestContext context ) 
{
    List<XmlTest> tests = context.getSuite().getXmlSuite().getTests();
    Map<String, String> suiteParams = context.getSuite().getXmlSuite().getAllParameters();
    Object[][] testData = new Object[tests.size()][2];
    int i = 0;
    for ( XmlTest thisTest : tests ) {
        testData[i][0] = new FirefoxDriver();
        testData[i][1] = thisTest.getName();
        i++;
        Reporter.log( i +  ": Added test: " + thisTest.getName(), true );
    }
    return testData;
}
....
@Test(dataProvider = "testdata", dataProviderClass = TestData.class)
    public void test2( FirefoxDriver se, String testName ) {
        Reporter.log("Thread-" + Thread.currentThread().getId() );
        se.navigateTo("http://google.com");
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to solve this.  One solution I can think of is ThreadLocal concept of Java. See this link for an example -http://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/
(See LocalDriverManager class).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I saw that example but wasn't 100% sure about implementation. Robbie's feedback seemed to have solved it for the setting name method, although I'm not sure if it will work for every example in my tests