# How to record and replicate my actions on multiple chromedrivers?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Basically I need to make a software that replicates my actions in a Chromedriver, in other Chromedrivers (with an undefined number, it could be 2, 4, 6, etc).

There will be a page (the same for all the web drivers) where I need to manually perform some actions. I want these actions to be repeated in real-time and in other Chrome tabs/windows.

For example, if I click on element X, then press Ctrl+V, then click on an input submit, or choose an option from a select, these actions must be repeated in the same order and in the same timing on other Chrome windows.

**Is there a way in selenium web driver or javascript to record which elements I interact with, and get a trustable Xpath of the element + the type of action performed?**

I was thinking of having multiple web drivers, one where I perform the actions, and the others where the actions are repeated. Then I would record my actions with Java and individually perform them in these other Chromedriver instances, but I don't know how to "record" them in the first place

Comment: For recording XPath's see [this discotion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8094844/6845383), for passing data between threads see [this discotion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23165184/6845383).